# How to alternate displayed text boxes after user entry to a chatbot so they go back and forth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a chatbot at the moment, and trying to connect a GUI I have been working with to the project.
It is running smooth but my output is a little messed up; in particular, the chat boxes should alternate between the user and the BOT, but they are stacking on top and not formatting correctly.

Ive tried anchoring the newest box with a margin-top, tried setting a counter variable to update the placement of each new box, etc., but am having trouble spacing them relative to each other.

Here is the most applicable CSS code of the general process:

```
#user_chatbox {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 30%;
}

#bot_chatbox {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

... and here is the .js code (within index.html) that is updating the blocks to be printed out with new information (input from the user and a reply from the bot):

```
<script>
        function getBotResponse() {
          var rawText = $("#textInput").val();
          var userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + '</span></p>';
          $("#textInput").val("");
          $("#user_chatbox").append(userHtml);
          document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
          $.get("/get", { msg: rawText }).done(function(data) {
            var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + '</span></p>';
            $("#bot_chatbox").append(botHtml);
            document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
          });
        }

        $("#textInput").keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                getBotResponse();
            }
        });

        $("#buttonInput").click(function() {
          getBotResponse();
        })
</script>
```

Nothing breaks, but I have attached some images below of the current output. Again, it isn't as much that the replies are basic right now, but rather that I want the displayed text blobs to be alternating from bot (right side) to user (left side).

[image: an example of the output not alternating. Should be a block on right then left then right then left...]

Comment: Im confused, it looks to me like the bot is on the right and the user is on the left, at least in your image.

Comment: Maybe the problem is because the messages are in different containers? Without the html, it won't be clear enough

Comment: invert your selector ?

Comment: @Laif Yea sorry if I wasnt particular enough; this end of things is pretty new to me so i guess I left out a few important pieces. The bot is on the right and user on the left; my goal is to keep it like that but have the messages stagger still (kind of like an iphone text chat).

Comment: @mthrsj thats definitely why it was working with a single container, but i couldn't figure out how to split the messages until I made two separate containers. Which worked but caused this new issue... Definitely open to a way to avoid two containers if you know how to still split sides like this.

Comment: @sawezo, you want to split sides and alternate the messages from bot and user? If so, you could use a single container, and use the position properties from css

Comment: @mthrsj Thats what I'm trying to figure out... I'm willing to change it to a single container but I dont want to lose the scrolling functionality I currently have. If I do it this way, I would just have a single container, say ```#bot_chatbox {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}```, then would need to alter the property based off of what side of the convo it was being changed by. Thats where I lose a bit of understanding. For example, in the .js, I would have ```$("#chatbox").append(botHtml);``` (instead of bot_chatbox) but how edit more?

Comment: @sawezo you need a custom css for the both message types, instead of the container. The `#bot_chatbox` css that you have, should be added to a `bot_message` class, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example on how to do the alternate bubbles that you want for the conversation. Let me know if this helps or I understood wrong what you needed.

```js
document.getElementById('send').onclick = function() {
  // User 
  let input = document.getElementById('userInput');
  
  let divNode = document.createElement('div'); 
  divNode.classList.add("message");
  divNode.classList.add("right");
  
  let textNode = document.createTextNode(input.value);
  divNode.appendChild(textNode);
  
  let chatbox = document.getElementById('chatbox');
  chatbox.appendChild(divNode);
  
  // Answer
  let divNodeAnswer = document.createElement('div'); 
  divNodeAnswer.classList.add("message");
  divNodeAnswer.classList.add("left");
  
  let textNodeAnswer = document.createTextNode("BLA BLA BLA");
  divNodeAnswer.appendChild(textNodeAnswer); 
  chatbox.appendChild(divNodeAnswer);
};
```

```css
#chatbox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
}

.message {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left {
  background: green;
}

.right{
  background: red; 
  float: right;
}

div#user {
  width: 200px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
  <div class="message spacer"></div>
  <div class="message left">Hi</div>
  <div class="message right">Wazzup</div>
  <div class="message left">bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="message left">ble ble ble ble ble ble ble</div>
  <div class="message right">bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<div id="user" ><input id="userInput" type="textbox" size="14"/><button id="send">Send</button>
```

Comment: This is close; basically the outcome I want but im trying to update the contents of each message blob as the program goes along.

Comment: Let me modify it a little

Comment: Ok. As you can see the top is currently using two containers. Doesnt need to stay that way as maybe thats why its a little funky now, but I dont want to lose the scroll functionality and such of the .js source code above.

Comment: I added some code to show you how you create elements, set the classes and append to the container `chatbox`. The scrolling can be added to the div element via css.

Comment: This isnt working with my code all, any way to plug it into what I have above to avoid redoing everything? This way isn't splitting the message blocks 50/50 like im trying to do

Comment: @sawezo, you might have to provide then a Minimal Reproducible Example so we can help you. I provided the help based on the information you shared. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Figured it out; thanks for the time! Will keep minimal reproducible examples in mind in future posts. Thanks!

Comment: @sawezo, The way I built my example was to first write the basic HTML. Then, I wrote the CSS while having in consideration that I would add/remove classes to the elements to affect their behavior, finally implemented the JavaScript.

Comment: Awesome; yea its been a little weird going from only coding in Python to trying to get the flow down with more interacting parts like this. thanks again!